# Environment variable to configure the location of the cpp source files

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am writing a cpp library for myself and I have put the deader files in a folder `<root>/include` and the cpp files in `<root>/src` folder. To add my include path to the environment, I have appended `<root>/include` to `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`. Now, the problem I am facing is that I am getting an error during the linking step because the linker is unable to find the implementation of my class. Is there any environment variable where I can mention this like the way I have done for the header files?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. The linker needs compiled code and cannot deal with your source files. What you can do is to write a Makefile that will compile all your source files in the /src folder and link compiled files to the target. Example of a Makefile doing this:

```
ROOT = YOUR_ROOT_DIRECTORY_HERE
LDFLAGS = OPTIONS_TO_LINKER_HERE
CPPFLAGS = OPTIONS_TO_COMPILER_HERE

SRC=$(wildcard $(ROOT)/src/*.cpp)

your_app: $(SRC)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Compile your application using: `make your_app`, or `make`.